# Run sequential process with scala future

Tags: scala, process, future

I have two external processes to be run sequentially:

```
  val antProc = Process(Seq(antBatch","everythingNoJunit"), new File(scriptDir))

  val bossProc = Process(Seq(bossBatch,"-DcreateConnectionPools=true"))

  val f: Future[Process] = Future {
    println("Run ant...")
    antProc.run
  }
  f onSuccess {
    case proc => {
      println("Run boss...")
      bossProc.run
    }
  }
```

The result is:

```
  Run ant...

  Process finished with exit code 0
```

How do I run antProc until completion, then bossProc?

The following method seems to achieve the purpose. However, it's not a Future approach.

```
    antProc.!<
    bossProc.!<
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
val antProc = Process(Seq(antBatch,"everythingNoJunit"), new File(scriptDir))
val bossProc = Process(Seq(bossBatch,"-DcreateConnectionPools=true"))
val antFut: Future[Process] = Future {      
  antProc.run
}
val bossFut: Future[Process] = Future {      
  bossProc.run
}
val aggFut = for{
  antRes <- antFut
  bossRes <- bossFut
} yield (antRes, bossRes)

aggFut onComplete{
  case tr => println(tr)
}
```

The result of the aggFut will be a tuple consisting of the ant result and the boss result.

Also, be sure your vm that is running this is not exiting before the async callbacks can occur.  If your execution context contains daemon threads then it might exit before completion.

Now if you want bossProc to run after antProc, the code would look like this

```
val antProc = Process(Seq(antBatch,"everythingNoJunit"), new File(scriptDir))
val bossProc = Process(Seq(bossBatch,"-DcreateConnectionPools=true"))
val antFut: Future[Process] = Future {      
  antProc.run
}
val aggFut = for{
  antRes <- antFut
  bossRes <- Future {bossProc.run}
} yield (antRes, bossRes)

aggFut onComplete{
  case tr => println(tr)
}
```

Comment: After I ran the code, it looked like antProc was started then bossProc without antProc being completed. I think I was not clear on the question. I was trying to start bossProc after antProc was done. Thank you though for the idea of aggregated Futures!

Comment: I edited the answer to show you how to make bossProc run after antProc completes.

Comment: I still have not been able to get it works with Future for some reason. I ended up using antProc.!< to block further execution until it is finished.